# Pass to a function several objects without copying them

Tags: c++

Consider C holds some resource and cannot be copyable.
What the best way to pass several C objects to some method (`hi_all` in an following simplified example of my problem)?

The only solution I found it to use `std::reference_wrapper`. Is there any better solution?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class C
{
public:
    C(int i)      throw() : i(i),   isCopy(false)    { }
    //C(const C& c) = delete; //actual version
    C(const C& c) throw() : i(c.i), isCopy(true)     { }
    C(C&& c)      throw() : i(c.i), isCopy(c.isCopy) { }    

    void hi() const
    {
        std::cout<<"hi:\t"<<i<<", copy:\t"<<isCopy<<std::endl;
    }

public:
    int i;
    bool isCopy;
};

void hi_all(const std::vector<C>& v)
{
    std::cout<<"copies"<<std::endl;
    for(auto &c : v)
        c.hi();
}

void hi_all(const std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<C>>& v)
{
    std::cout<<"ref wrappers"<<std::endl;
    for(auto &c : v)
        c.get().hi();
}

void hi_all(const std::vector<C>& v, std::function<bool (const C&)> predicate)
{
    std::cout<<"predicate"<<std::endl;
    for(auto &c : v)
    {
        if(predicate(c))
            c.hi();
    }
}

int main()
{
    //one external source of objects
    std::vector<C> v;
    v.push_back(C(1));
    v.push_back(C(2));
    v.push_back(C(3));

    //another source of objects. just one instance for simplicity
    C another_c(4);

    std::vector<C> v2;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<C>> v2_ref;

    for(auto &c : v)
    {
        if(c.i > 1)
        {
            v2.push_back(c); //fail: copy ctor
            v2_ref.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<C>(c));
        }
    }

    v2.push_back(another_c); //fail: copy ctor
    v2_ref.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<C>(another_c));

    hi_all(v2);
    hi_all(v2_ref);
    hi_all(v, [](const C& c){ return c.i > 1; }); //fail: another_c lost.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you pass the vector by reference, then nothing should be copied. So I kind of fail to see your problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg what about `another_c`? I have to pass all objects in a single call (it's actually call of constructor).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I suppose that a problem arises if the objects passed need not belong to one container, or they should be passed with some non-trivial ordering.

Comment: @lisyarus order doesn't matter. Right, they don't belong to one container. That is problem.

Comment: @lorond just some thoughts concerning usecase :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution with `reference_wrapper` seems good enough to me. Note that you could also use a vector of pointers, if you feel better with them (but I  **strongly insist** that your solution with references is more clear, as it is far more *logically correct*).

If you still want to make it simpler/better, I see two ways.

Firstly, you can just pass `v` and `another_C` to you function as separate arguments. Fast, simple, but not very scalable (probably you don't need it here?).

Secondly, you can create some generic wrappers that will generate vectors of references, and use them in this code.

By the way, if you know the number of objects at compile-time (which, unfortunatelly, seems not to be the case), you could use variadic templates.

Similar approach can be used to create wrappers:

```
template <typename T>
using refs_vector_t = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<T>>;

template <typename T>
void refs_vector_impl (refs_vector_t<T> & result) { }

template <typename ... Ts>
void refs_vector_impl (refs_vector_t<T> & result, T const & x, Ts const & ... ts)
{
    result.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<T>(x));
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
}

// assuming Con is a container of T
template <typename Con, typename ... Ts>
void refs_vector_impl (refs_vector_t<T> & result, Con const & con, Ts const & ... ts)
{
    for (auto const & x : con)
        refs_vector_impl(result, x);
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
refs_vector_t<T> refs_vector (Ts const & ... ts)
{
    refs_vector_t<T> result;
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
    return result;
}
```

Then, somewhere in your code:

```
hi_all(refs_vector<C>(v, another_C));
```

Comment: Number of objects is unknown at compile time. Pointers was previous solution. Right now I'm doing refactoring to get rid of pointer as much as possible.

Comment: reference_wrapper is better than pointer because it enforces logical correctness - a reference_wrapper cannot be null, so it eliminates the need for redundant checks and error handling (or worse, forgetting to put them in).

Comment: @RichardHodges agree. That's exatcly what I meant by calling this solution more clear.

Comment: @lisyarus I see. I was concerned that the phrase "Note that you could also use a vector of pointers, if you feel better with them" might give younger developers the idea that using pointers was OK. It's not - they should be avoided at all costs! :-)

Comment: @RichardHodges they definitelly should avoid them, I just didn't want to be too obsessive :) I'll update the answer.

Comment: @RichardHodges Both references and pointers have their downsides. A pointer-free program might not dereference null-pointers, but references have the downside of not showing what variables a function may change at the calling site: `foo(&bar)` makes it very clear that the call may change the `bar` variable, if `foo()` takes a reference, that information is lost. My experience is that segfaults are at least easy to debug (fails early, noisily, and points the debugger at the right place), hunting down why results are wrong (due to inadvertent change of local variables) is less easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'll place fixed and more generalized @lisyarus's solution. It's close enough to what I wanted. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```cpp
template <typename T>
using refs_vector = std::vector < std::reference_wrapper<T> >;

template <typename T>
static void refs_vector_impl(refs_vector<T> & result) { }

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
static void refs_vector_impl(refs_vector<T> & result, T & x, Ts & ... ts)
{
    result.push_back(std::reference_wrapper<T>(x));
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
}

// assuming Con is a container of T
template <typename T, typename Con, typename ... Ts>
static void refs_vector_impl(refs_vector<T> & result, Con & con, Ts & ... ts)
{
    for (auto & x : con)
        refs_vector_impl(result, x);
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
}

/* non constant references */
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
refs_vector<T> refs(Ts& ... ts)
{
    refs_vector<T> result;
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
    return result;
}

/* constant references */
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
refs_vector<T const> crefs(Ts const & ... ts)
{
    refs_vector<T const> result;
    refs_vector_impl(result, ts...);
    return result;
}
```